# Relation between computing determinant using the traditional method taught vs computing the determinant using L2 norm

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, normed-spaces

I watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ip3X9LOh2dk to understand determinant of matrices, and understood the concept of how it is used to measure the area scaled using the transformation. Lets take a 2D matrix, say.,

**[[2, 1], [3, 2]]** where i vector = [2, 1] and j vector = [3, 2], the determinant turns out to be 1. Essentially, it captures the new area after the transformation. Now in the 2D space, we can measure the area by base * height. Which means if I consider i vector as my base and j vector as my height and I apply L2 norm to find the length of i and j vectors, and mulitply the L2 norm of these vectors, it should have also given the determinant which is not the case. Am I missing anything? Why would determinant not match my area computation using L2 norm?

Also, I am aware that using L2 norm doesn't capture the flip of space, where determinant would have given a negative result

Comment: Please focus on one question in a post.

Comment: Base times perpendicular height.

Comment: Note that if the vectors are not perpendicular, then the volume will necessarily be less than the product of the L2 norms. This fact is known as [Hadamard's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality)

Comment: When you assume that the length of one vector is the base and that the length of the second vector is the height, you assume that the second vector is perpendicular to the first. In general, the height that we should multiply by is the "altitude" of the parallelogram.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I got it